# How to do groupby().sum() but not sum values for repeated value in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I have the following `df`.

```
  wallet        position  position_rewards position_type token_transfers  total_position_rewards  rewards_pct  transfers_per_rewards 
0  0x123            FRAX               700            LD           450            1000                    0.7                    315           
0  0x123            USDC               200            LD           450            1000                    0.2                     90            
0  0x123             ETH               100      Sushi_LP           450            1000                    0.1                     45            
1  0xabc             FXS                40            LD             5              50                    0.8                      4            
1  0xabc             ETH                10      Sushi_LP             5              50                    0.2                      1
```

**A few notes about the data:**

- The values in the columns `total_transfers` and `total_position_rewards` are "aggregated" by wallet. That is, each wallet has only one value for that column, even though the wallet is repeated throughout the `df` (because other values in the other columns differ).

**What I want to output:**

I am interested in creating a table/showing/charting the amount of `token_transfers` per `position_type`.

One wallet can have different `positions`, but the `position_type`can be the same (see wallet `0x123`).

`total_position_rewards` is a sum of all `position_rewards`for a given wallet and `rewards_pct` is basically `position_rewards` divided by `total_position_rewards`.

What I want to calculate is the `total_token_transfers_per_position_type`. Which means that I would need to group `token_transfers` per `position_type`, but since the values `token_transfers` are only one for each wallet, I cannot do `df.groupby(['wallet', 'position_type'])['token_transfers'].sum()` because I do not want the `sum` of `token_transfers`,  but its `sum` across `wallet` and `positon_type` (and NOT sum these values within the wallet).

**My code:**

```
df.groupby(['wallet', 'position_type'])['token_transfers'].sum()
```

As stated above, I need ot somehowe ignore values being summed across wallet, only across `position_type`.

For example, if you do the above operation, I would get the following results for `total_token_transfers_per_position_type`:

```
LD: 450 + 450 + 5 = 905

Sushi_LP: 450 + 5 = 455
```

however, the correct result should be:

```
LD: 450 + 5 = 455

Sushi_LP: 450 + 5 = 455
```

Basically, I need to sum `token_transfers` across each `position_type`, but not summing them up within wallets.

If I do a `df.groupby('wallet')['token_transfers'].sum()` and one wallet has mulitple `positon_types`, I will get wrongly summed values.

If I do a `df.groupby('position_type')['token_transfers'].sum()` `pandas` will wrongly sum the values within each wallet.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: I tried doing `df.groupby(['wallet', 'position_type'])['token_transfers'].sum()`. It does not work since it sums up duplicated values for each wallet. I need to ignore the duplicates for each row and sum the values by position_type and wallet (again, not summing up the values within one single wallet).

Comment: show your code in question (not in comments). It would be simpler if you would create minimal working code (with example data in code) which we could copy to use in solutions.

Comment: frankly I don't understand all your idea but if you want to reduce duplicated values then you always can use `set()` for this. `set([450, 450, 5])` gives `(450, 5)`. And I think `pandas` should also have function like `unique`

Comment: Added little section to original post. How do I go about summing up `set()` values only for each wallet. Because let's say that 2 different rows have the same value `450`, for example, I do not want to ignore them. I just want to ignore duplicates within wallets.

Comment: you can use `for`-loop to work with groups. But maybe you should first remove duplicate values in wallets and later try to sum values.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Also not sure how/where the `for` loop would fit into the `groupby()`. Yeah, I just don't know how to do a grouped sum with dropped values within rows. How do I rmeove duplicates within rows and not acress an entire column.

Comment: `for key, value in df.groupby(..): ... set(values)...`

Comment: I'll try that but will also try with some sort of combination between `stack()` and `unstack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your idea but you can always use `for`-loop to work with every group separatelly and later use `set()` to reduce duplicated

Something like this:

```
text = '''wallet        position  position_rewards position_type token_transfers  total_position_rewards  rewards_pct  transfers_per_rewards 
0x123            FRAX               700            LD           450            1000                    0.7                    315           
0x123            USDC               200            LD           450            1000                    0.2                     90            
0x123             ETH               100      Sushi_LP           450            1000                    0.1                     45            
0xabc             FXS                40            LD             5              50                    0.8                      4            
0xabc             ETH                10      Sushi_LP             5              50                    0.2                      1'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')
#print(df)

for key, val in df.groupby(['position_type']):
    print('key:', key)
    print('token_transfers:', val['token_transfers'].to_list())
    print('set:', set(val['token_transfers']))
    print('sum:', sum(set(val['token_transfers'])))
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
key: LD
token_transfers: [450, 450, 5]
set: {450, 5}
sum: 455
---
key: Sushi_LP
token_transfers: [450, 5]
set: {450, 5}
sum: 455
---
```

Maybe it could be coded using some `.map` or `.agg` on group but using `for`-loop you have simpler access to groups and you can simpler use standard functions from Python.

---

**EDIT:**

Using `apply()` I can execute `sum(set(x))`

```
print( df.groupby('position_type')['token_transfers'].apply(lambda x:sum(set(x))) )
```

or `.apply(set).apply(sum)` (because `.apply(set).sum()` doesn't work)

```
print( df.groupby('position_type')['token_transfers'].apply(set).apply(sum) )
```

Result:

```
position_type
LD          455
Sushi_LP    455
Name: token_transfers, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does `set()` ignore values that are the same across different wallets?

Comment: `set` ignores values which you have in group - it doesn't care what it is. if you need something more complex then you have to show example date and expected result in question. And it may need to more complex code. And this is why I don't understand your idea. Maybe it will need to create groups inside groups to reduce duplicates.

Comment: I made an edit at the end explaining why I can't do `df.groupby('wallet')['token_transfers'].sum()` nor `df.groupby('position_type')['token_transfers'].sum()`. Maybe it helps, and yeah, it probably requires groups within groups because I need to drop duplicates for each group.

Comment: It would be simpler if you add example data which better shows problem - and add expected result. We could use it to create better solution.

Comment: I created another question, with simpler and clearer example and questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73749095/how-to-sum-values-across-groups-without-summing-duplicates