# How to sum values across groups without summing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following `df`:

```
     A    B        C       D 
0  foo    a     1200     300  
0  foo    a      700     300  
0  foo    b     1000     300         
1  bar    b      270      70 
1  bar    a      350      70
2  abc    c      270     300 
2  abc    a      350     300
```

I want to display the sum of values in column `D` grouped by column `B`, but I do not want to sum the values in column `B` for a single value in column `A`. That is, column `D` has only one value per value in column `A`.

`foo` will only ever have the value `300` and `bar` will only have the value `70` in column `D`. The values in this column are just repeated because I have repeated indexes.

I want to print something like (no need to show formatting, I just need to output the correct sums):

```
a: 300 (from foo) + 300 (from foo) + 70 (from bar) = 670
b: 300 (from foo) + 70 (from bar) = 370
c: 300 (from abc)
```

That is, values in column `D` should not be summed together if the value in column `A` is the same among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pd.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique) after the groupby and then sum those values up.

```
df.groupby('B')['D'].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.unique(x)))
```

```
B
a    370
b    370
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

**UPDATE**
For your new example you search for something like this:

```
df.groupby(['B','A'])['D'].apply(lambda x: sum(pd.unique(x))).groupby('B').sum()
```

Output:

```
B
a    670
b    370
c    300
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does this still solve it after my change? That is, see how the number 300 is repeated  across different values in column `A`. I need to sum up the 300s that appear for different ones in `B` but not in `D`.

Comment: did you try it with your new example? why is there  twice 300 in `a` from foo. you explicitely didn't want that.

Comment: The reason only the number 300 appears in every foo row and 70 appears in every bar row is because the values in column `D`, in the data I'm trying to handle is unique to each value in column `A`.That is why I explain in the post: "foo will only ever have the value 300 and bar will only have the value 70 in column D. The values in this column are just repeated because I have repeated indexes."

Comment: yes I get that. But in your new example for `a`. you write: "300 (from foo) + 300 (from foo) + 70 (from bar)" this is twice 300 where column A is `foo` and column b is `a`, so it is a duplicate sum which you clearly didnt want.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you have a mistake in your desired output. thats why I was confused. for `a` it has to be: "300 (from foo) + 70 (from bar) + 300 (from abc) "

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I did want to count it ion, because I need to sum across a, b, c (my final print will show a, b c, so if the value is 300 for b, but for different ones in column A (foo, bar, abc), then I do want to include that second 300, because even though it is still a, it comes from a different one in column `A`. yes exactly, 300 + 70 + 300, sorry.